# Using muzzley to communicate alljoyn signals over cloud

Tags: cloud, iot, alljoyn

I want to create an App which will be able to communicate over cloud using alljoyn . While searching over net i got some information about muzzley ,Does muzzley provide supported cloud interface for Android apps to communicate over Internet. It can be a simple app say chatting . Are there some apps using muzzley for cloud communication in google playstore ?

Has someone used muzzley interfaces to communicate alljoyn messages over cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My name is Jorge Claro and I’m part of Muzzley engineering team.

Muzzley is a mobile app and a cloud platform that enables manufacturers and developers to connect their IoT devices to the end-user and provide some features like manual interaction or automation.

You can develop your own “widget” to communicate with your device. It’s very easy and once you do it, it will automatically appear inside the Muzzley mobile app (search for muzzley on Google Play).

Regarding the Alljoyn protocol, we already have a draft connector using the LSF to control bulbs, and, the Alljoyn core to control the power plugs. The code is available on github and there is also a video available on youtube where you can find the following:

- Discovering the Alljoyn gateway and the local networked devices (bulbs)
- Controlling the lamp through the internet on a 3G/LTE connection.

Code here: https://github.com/muzzley/alljoyn-muzzley-connector

Video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STGvBIByFJI

This example is targeted to run on a x86-64 or openWRT platforms. If you’d like to test drive it, please contact our support team at support@muzzley.com. As this is a Alljoyn preview connector you don’t have it publicly available and you’ll need some access tokens.

Finally, we are always trying to grow our list of compatible devices, so if you would like to develop your own device integration using the Muzzley app, even without alljoyn, we’d love to help you.

Best regards,

Jorge Claro

Systems Integrator

Allseen Alliance Developer

Comment: Hi Jorge,
Thank you for the response, i am not making any device. I just want to use Muzzley's Alljoyn gateway connector for my Android app so that two android devices running my app over internet connection will be able to transfer data. Is it possible using muzzley ?

Currently i am not building anything to remote control using Muzzley app . Please let me know if my understanding is correct.

Comment: I am running the sample provided by you in the link https://github.com/muzzley/muzzley-alljoyn-integration-demo , i tried to run it on two devices connected to same wifi, it is working with same wifi but not working over internet when the devices are not connected to same wifi. Is there anything i need to do .

Comment: This issue should have been resolved and it was handled at the project's GitHub repo: https://github.com/muzzley/muzzley-alljoyn-integration-demo/issues/1